# Setting height based on another elements height over multiple instances in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, function

I'm using jQuery to obtain the height from one div and add that via css into another

So i have the following layout as an example:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="column image">
    <img src="image.jpg" />
  </div>
  <div class="column content">
    <p>Content</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="column content">
    <p>Content</p>
  </div>
  <div class="column image">
    <img src="image.jpg" />
  </div>
</div>
```

with the following jQuery

```
function showHeight( element, height ) {
$( "div.image" ).css("height", height);
}

showHeight( "div", $( ".content" ).height() );
```

where i would take the height from ".content" & recur that height into ".image"

now obviously this works for say one instance but I'm looking to have this over multiple instances rather than write a function for each.

Comment: `$( "div.image" ).each(function(){$(this).css("height", $(this).prev().height())})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop through the `.image` elements and change its `height` according to the `prev('.content')` element.

```
function updateHeight() {
    // loop through all image elements
    $( "div.image" ).each(function(){
        // get `height` of the previous `.content` element
        var contentHeight = $(this).prev('.content').height();

        // set height
        $(this).css("height", contentHeight);
    });
}

//call one method to update 
updateHeight();
```

This will only work when the `.image` comes after `.content`. I reordered the HTML like this:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="column content">
    <p>Content</p>
  </div>
  <div class="column image">
    <img src="image.jpg" />
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="column content">
    <p>Content</p>
  </div>
  <div class="column image">
    <img src="image.jpg" />
  </div>
</div>
```

#### UPDATE:

To find closest .content in any order, change this

```
var contentHeight = $(this).prev('.content').height();
```

to

```
var contentHeight = $(this).prev('.content').height() || $(this).next('.content').height();
```

Comment: I specifically had the "columns" arranged as per shown but the update works as intended thank you.